# Cannot satisfy dependency when trying to install the Android Development Tools plug-in for Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin

I have been fighting with this for a couple of hours now. I have downloaded the Eclipse IDE for Java EE developers from this link: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/heliossr1

Here are the messages I am receiving when I try to install the ADT plug-in:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Android Hierarchy Viewer 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.group 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.3.1.20100916-1202 (epp.package.jee 1.3.1.20100916-1202)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Eclipse UI 3.6.1.M20100826-1330 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.1.M20100826-1330)
    Eclipse UI 3.6.2.M20110203-1100 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2.M20110203-1100)
    Eclipse UI 3.6.0.I20100603-1100 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.0.I20100603-1100)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Hierarchy Viewer 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.group 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534)
    To: org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.3.1.20100916-1202 (epp.package.jee 1.3.1.20100916-1202)
    To: org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group [1.3.1.20100916-1202]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Java EE IDE Feature 1.3.1.20100916-1202 (org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group 1.3.1.20100916-1202)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.6.1.r361_v20100909-9gF78GrkFqw7GrsZnvz0JWNTeb6fue6896L]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.6.1.r361_v20100909-9gF78GrkFqw7GrsZnvz0JWNTeb6fue6896L (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.6.1.r361_v20100909-9gF78GrkFqw7GrsZnvz0JWNTeb6fue6896L)
    To: org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [3.6.1.r361_v20100827-9OArFLdFjY-ThSQXmKvKz0_T]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse RCP 3.6.1.r361_v20100827-9OArFLdFjY-ThSQXmKvKz0_T (org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group 3.6.1.r361_v20100827-9OArFLdFjY-ThSQXmKvKz0_T)
    To: org.eclipse.ui [3.6.1.M20100826-1330]
```

Answer (score 2):

> Only one of the following can be installed at once

In the Install New Software window , uncheck 'Contact all update sites during install to find required software' and proceed with adding the ADT Plugin. Make sure you have Eclipse Helios Service Release 2 (3.6.2) or greater. Only Helios SR2 or greater supports the latest version of ADT Plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Java Plain is the preferred installation, dont install Java EE.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't matter if you're using Eclipse for Java EE. That's the version that I always use because I like the Java EE perspective. What version of the SDK do you have installed?  Honestly since Eclipse is a standalone executable, I'd just try downloading a fresh version of Indigo since there's no installer and just go from there. Also, what version of the JDK do you have installed? I've never tried Android with Java 7

Comment: I have been sidetracked onto another project but will be getting back to this as soon as possible. Thanks for the reply. I haven't forgotten about it.